# jQuery Hit Testing over Image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single, fixed-sized image of 5 stars (each star also being a fixed-width). I would like to track and respond as the use hovers over each of the 5 stars.

I've done some Googling but didn't find a clear way to approach this in JavaScript/jQuery. I know there are APIs for getting the mouse coordinates, but how can I get coordinates within the image?

Any tips or links for getting the mouse coordinates relative to an an image being hovered over?

Comment: 5 different elements don't work for your scenario?

Comment: I could probably make them work, but the same image is used elsewhere and a single image works best for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an image map:

1. Create five HTML image map areas using [Image Mapper,](http://www.image-mapper.com/) being sure to add one "hotspot" for each of the five stars.
2. Use the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on the `area` elements to trigger an action when the mouse pointer collides with and leaves a star.

**Demo**

Reusing the star image from [Prisoner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16989092/88487):

http://jsfiddle.net/4GgBu/1/

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/CwkF2Hr.jpg" usemap="#image-map" />
<map name="image-map" id="image-map">
    <area shape="poly" class="star" coords=" 79,11, 63,56, 13,59, 52,91, 36,139, 79,110, 120,139, 105,91, 147,59, 95,56, 79,10" href="#" alt="star 1" />
    <area shape="poly" class="star" coords=" 257,9, 241,59, 189,59, 232,91, 215,139, 256,109, 300,138, 285,89, 325,59, 274,58, 259,13" href="#" alt="star 2" />
    <area shape="poly" class="star" coords=" 420,58, 367,58, 409,89, 393,138, 436,110, 478,140, 463,90, 504,59, 453,57, 436,11, 420,55" href="#" alt="star 3" />
    <area shape="poly" class="star" coords=" 614,12, 596,58, 549,60, 587,89, 571,138, 613,111, 656,141, 640,88, 679,58, 631,57, 618,15" href="#" alt="star 4" />
    <area shape="poly" class="star" coords=" 774,58, 726,60, 767,88, 750,139, 792,110, 835,140, 819,91, 862,58, 808,56, 791,9, 776,57" href="#" alt="star 5" />
</map>

<p class="message">Rollover a star to see this message update.</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $stars = $(".star");

$stars.mouseover(function(e){
    var starID = $stars.index(e.target) + 1;
    $('.message').text('Star ' + starID + ' rolled over');   
});

$stars.mouseout(function(e){
    var starID = $stars.index(e.target) + 1;
    $('.message').text('Star ' + starID + ' rolled out');
});
```

Comment: I will need some time to try and understand this. What's with all the coordinate values? Perhaps you are actually defining the stars there? Note that that isn't necessary. If you imagine a square around each star, I only want to know when the mouse is in that square.

Comment: Yes, the coordinates describe the stars. (This is the code that Image Mapper generates when you upload an image and trace the shapes you're interested in manually.) If you're just concerned with a rough rectangular hit area, you could simplify those areas greatly with *shape="[rect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area)"*. Or simply use one image repeated five times – one for each star – and subscribe to mouseover and mouseout events for those.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this (can be optimised, I just rushed it):

Javascript

```
var NUMBER_STARS = 5
$("img").click(function(e){
    var left = e.pageX-$(this).offset().left;
    var selected_stars = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < NUMBER_STARS; i++){
        if($(this).width() / NUMBER_STARS * i < left){
            selected_stars++;
        }
    }
    alert(selected_stars);
});
```

Just a little css for the cursor:
    img{
        width: 300px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

HTML

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/CwkF2Hr.jpg" />
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wp7sg/1/